# convert from Mat to Matx33f

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a way to convert a Mat object into small matrix (matrix of the form: Matx22f, Matx33f, etc..)?

I know that the opposite is possible - convert from Matx33f to Mat for example).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It's possible `Matx22f` is a typedef for `Matx<float,2,2>` which have a constructor that get a pointer to array of elements :

```
explicit Matx(const _Tp* vals); //!< initialize from a plain array
```

So you can convert your mat to c style array and send it to Matx :

```
cv::Mat mat(2,2, CV_32F);
float* data = reinterpret_cast<float*>(mat.data);//cast mat.data to float*
cv::Matx22f converted(data);//make Matx22f
```

Or if you want copy elements before constructing Matx22f :

```
cv::Mat mat(2,2, CV_32F);
float* data = reinterpret_cast<float*>(mat.data);
int size = mat.rows * mat.cols;
std::vector<float> vec(size);
std::copy(data + 0, data + size, vec.begin());
cv::Matx22f converted(&vec[0]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer. Your solution seems to work but looks a bit tedious :-) I'm wondering if there is a somehow simpler solution.

Comment: I didn't see your last post. I'll try this solution - thanks a lot.

Comment: This will fail if you have stride in the Mat object.